# Почему не запускается программа после конвертации в .exe?

Tags: python, pygame, pyinstaller

Всем привет!
Столкнулся с такой проблемой, сконвертировал примитивную игру через `pyinstaller` в .exe формат, игра основана на библиотеке `pygame`, и после запуска игры мне всплыло окно с ошибкой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в чем может быть дело?
спасибо

Comment: Я не знаю питона, не знаю чем вы это запаковывали, но, даже я имею представления что вам надо хотябы объяснить, как вы настраивали ваш компилятор/сборщик, и что вы на каждом шаге делали, чтобы люди имели представление где могла быть допущена ошибка. А сейчас нет ни кода, ни того чем вы его собирали, ни параметров сборки. Вы верите что вам смогут ответить по существу?

Comment: да, файл `pyg.py`, я сначала произвел вот эту команду: `pyinstaller -w -F pyg.py` после этого попытался запустить сконвертированную программу, а она не запускается..
Потом поазил в интернете, и в одном из сайтов было написано, что в файл `pyg.spec` нужно добавить ссылку на изображения, которые используются в игре, сделал как они сказали, и после этого произвел вот эту команду `pyinstaller pyg.spec` так же создался ЕХЕшник, запускаю его - и все та же ошибка всплывает

Comment: Дело может быть в том, что питоньи скрипты не очень-то предназначены для такого способа распространения.

Comment: pyinstaller позволяет добавлять библиотеки в сборку, возможно их не хватает. Распакуйте получившийся архив например с помощью winrar и проверьте все ли зависимости на месте.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, не могли бы обосновать почему вдруг скрипты не предназначены для такого варианта распространения, тот же autoit  изначально на это рассчитан.

Comment: @Igor потому, например, что сам Питон "из коробки" не умеет делать исполняемые файлы.